# Verifying if layer is filtered using PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, fields-attributes, filter, vector-layer

I have loaded multiples duplicated layers in QGIS with different filters. I wonder if it is possible to find the layers that haven't any filter (`setSubsetString` method) with PyQGIS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### PyQGIS 2

Loop over all registered layers and check if [`subsetString`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#a7eca0cb9c06c191fdd43a5fddd9ff4d7) is empty.

```py
layers = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers()

for name, layer in layers.items():
    if not layer.subsetString():
        print 'layer %s has empty subsetString'% name
```

Answer (score 3):

### PyQGIS 3

Adopted version of @Detlev's answer:

```py
from qgis.core import QgsProject, QgsVectorLayer

layers = QgsProject.instance().mapLayers()

for layer in layers.values():
    if isinstance(layer, QgsVectorLayer):
        if not layer.subsetString():
            print(f"Layer '{layer.sourceName()}' has empty subsetString")
```

or

```py
from qgis.core import QgsProject, QgsVectorLayer

layers_not_filtered = [
    lyr for lyr in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers()
    if isinstance(lyr, QgsVectorLayer) and
    not lyr.subsetString()
]

fmt_print = lambda lyr: print(f"Layer '{lyr.name()}' has empty subsetString")
_ = list(map(fmt_print, layers_not_filtered))
```

Comment: @J.Monticolo, thank you for your magic (even if it is a bit longer ^_^)

Comment: I disagree, 4 lines. And the goal is to get a list of not filtered layers, achieved in one line instead of 5.